# How to get sum null values as zero while using group by

Tags: mysql

I have mysql query

```
SELECT date, COALESCE(SUM(events),0) AS hotel_c
FROM event_cohort_report
WHERE date >= '2015-08-05' AND campaign='Pointific_Incent' AND country='IN'
GROUP BY date
```

when i run this query i get this result

```
date       hotel_c
2015-08-07 5411
2015-08-08 4602
2015-08-09 5151
2015-08-10 183
2015-08-11 1
```

But i want for all date sum with zero if its not present in the table something like this.

```
date       hotel_c
2015-08-05 0
2015-08-06 0
2015-08-07 5411
2015-08-08 4602
2015-08-09 5151
2015-08-10 183
2015-08-11 1
```

Comment: Do rows with those dates exist in the table at all?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are using is correct for getting value for null records. But I don't know the table and records in that as you have not mentioned. I have a working modal on this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7b42/1)

You can also use `IFNULL(SUM(column),0)` for replacing `null` with `0`

Comment: To satisfy OP requirements your SQL Fiddle example should show zero counts for 1st, 2nd & 3rd of August as the start date for your query was 1st August.

Comment: that's fetched from the records of the table. I do not have records for those date

Comment: That's the point of the original question - see the answer to the first comment.